# Arbitrary constant C, when to resolve it to C?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, constants

[image]

in the picture on top, we resolve the arbitrary constant from $-2C_1$ to C, by why don't we do so when it is $\frac{10}{C}$ (below)?
**In essence, why isn't $y=\frac {10}{e^x}+C$ correct?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that $C$ is also an arbitrary constant. And therefore you can write it as, say, $10K$, in which case $\frac{10}y=e^z+C$ becomes $\frac{10}y=e^z+10K$, and therefore$$y=\frac1{e^z/10+K}.$$But you will *never* get $\frac{10}{e^z}+C$ by this process.

Comment: If we divided both sides of $\frac{10}{} = ^z+ $ by 10 we would get $\frac{1}{} = \frac {^z}{10}+\frac{}{10}$, which would then resut in $\frac{1}{} = \frac {^z}{10}+\frac{}{10}= \frac {^z}{10}+$. Which we can then take the reciprocal to determine that $ = \frac {10}{^z}+\frac{10}{} =  \frac {10}{^z}+$. Wouldn't that result in $\frac {10}{^z}+$, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How do you go from $\frac{10}y=e^z+C$ to $\frac1y=\frac{10}{e^z}+\frac{10}C$? What you should get is $\frac1y=\frac{e^z}{10}+\frac C{10}$.

Comment: sorry was hard to visualize the code without sending it first. had to edit. Completed now and thanks for the response btw!

Comment: How do you go from $\frac1y=\frac{e^z}{10}+C$ to $y=\frac{10}{e^z}+C$?

Comment: By multiplying y on both sides, then divide both sides by $\frac {^z}{10}+C$? For example: $1 = y(\frac {^z}{10}+C), then \frac {1}{\frac{^z}{10} + C}=y$

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $y$, you get $1=\frac{e^zy}{10}+Cy$. And now, if you divide both sides by $\frac{e^z}{10}+C$, what you get is$$\frac1{\frac{e^z}{10}+C}=y.$$How is this the same thing as $y=\frac{10}{e^z}+C$?

Comment: Because doesn't it becomes $\frac {10}{^z}+ \frac{1}{C}$, and since C is an arbitrary number $\frac{1}{C} = C$? Which then result in $y=\frac{10}{e^z}+C$?

Comment: Are you saying that$$\frac1{\frac{e^z}{10}+C}=\frac{10}{e^z}+\frac1C?$$

Comment: I'm starting to see that my algebra basics is wrong here.. $\frac1{\frac{e^z}{10}+C} \neq \frac{10}{e^z}+\frac{1}{C}$, is it...?

Comment: Very much so, if you happen to believe that $\frac1{a+b}=\frac1a+\frac1b$.

Comment: Wow. I guess my ape brain though it if $\frac{a}{10}+\frac{b}{10} = \frac{a+b}{10}$ then it'd apply for numerators too, but it doesn't does it(!)

Answer (score 2):

They are very different functions. Try to sketch them. As $x\rightarrow\infty$, one tends to $C$ and the other tends to $10/C$.

This basically comes down to the fact that you can’t write

$$\frac{b}{a+c}=\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}.$$

Sure, if, on the other hand, you had

$$\frac{e^x+C}{10}=\frac{e^x}{10}+\underbrace{\frac{C}{10}}_{C_1}$$

you could have relabelled the constants.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the results. The solution space of a differential equation is not always of the form "some function plus a constant", especially if a $y$ term appears on the right-hand side. In other words,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 (y(x) + C)}{\partial x^2}  = \frac{\partial^2 y(x)}{\partial x^2}
$$
but
$$
-\frac{e^x (y(x)+C)^2}{10} \neq -\frac{e^x y(x)^2}{10}
$$
(Maybe it's true for some values of $C$ such as $C=0$, but I'm writing that this is not an equality for all $C$.)

So the reasoning is different. So far, this has probably not been very helpful to you though. The thing that you need to remember when you're computing is that you can only replace $kC$ by $C$ if you're looking at the final solution, i.e. $y(x) = f(x) + kC$; in this case it is fine to replace $kC$ by $C$ since $C$ is arbitrary and the family $\{f(x) + kC \, | \, C \in \mathbb R \}$ is the same family as the family $\{f(x) + C \, | \, C \in \mathbb R\}$ because those are just two parametrizations of the same family.

Similarly, if $y(x) = e^C f(x)$ for some constant $C$ (as a solution of some other differential equation), you could re-write this as $y(x) = C f(x)$ for $C > 0$ since the families $\{e^Cf(x) \, | \, C \in \mathbb R \}$ and $\{Cf(x) \, | \, C > 0 \}$ parametrize the same solutions. So this statement about $C$ is really about re-parametrizing the solution space to simplify the description of the family, so when you do it, you need to check if you are describing the same space of solutions.

Hope that helps,